# Show that a $N$-body Schrodinger operator has compact resolvent

Tags: operator-theory, quantum-mechanics, compact-operators, laplacian

I have a $N$-body Sch\"odinger operator of the following form
\begin{equation}
H := \sum_{j=1}^{N} (-\Delta_{x_j}+U_{trap}(x_j))+\sum_{i<j} V(x_i-x_j),
\end{equation}
where $U_{trap}$ is a positive function that traps, namely
\begin{equation}
\lim_{|x|\to+\infty}U(x)=+\infty,
\end{equation}
and $V$ has the property
\begin{equation}
V^2(x)\le C(1-\Delta_x).
\end{equation}
The Hamiltonian $H$ acts on the bosonic Hilbert space $L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)^{\otimes_{\operatorname{sym}}N}$.

I need to show that $H$ has compact resolvent, and I know that the kinetic part has compact resolvent. Could you help me in showing that the interaction between particles does not spoil the property?
Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by $V^2(x)\le C(1-\Delta_x)$ and "kinetic part"?

Comment: I mean that the inequality holds for example in the sense of quadratic forms on $L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$ for some constant $C>0$. By kinetic part I mean $\sum_{j=1}^N (-\Delta_{x_j}+U_{trap}(x_j))$